# A monic quartic polynomial with $4$ distinct real roots whose turning points determine an equilateral triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, maxima-minima

A monic quartic polynomial with 4 distinct real roots, such that if we were to construct a triangle whose vertices are the polynomials' 3 turning points, the triangle formed is equilateral Find the area of a triangle.

Can I take $(0,0)$ as a turning point?

On taking $(0,0)$ as a turning point I am getting $3^{0.83}$

Am I right? Please provide a precise solution or hint.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the polynomial is $p(x)$.  If the turning points (the roots of $p'(x)$) are at $x=a,b,c$, we have $p'(x) = 4 (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$.  Since the formulation is invariant under translation, we may assume wlog $a=0 < b < c$.  Then $p'(x) = 4 x (x-b)(x-c)$, and
$p(x) = {x}^{4}+4/3\, \left( -b-c \right) {x}^{3}+2\,bc{x}^{2}+d$ for some $d$.
The three turning points are $(0,d)$, $(b, -{b}^{4}/3 +2{b}^{3}c/3+d)$ and
$(c,-{c}^{4}/3+2b{c}^{3}/3+d)$.  Setting these to be equidistant, I get two equations in $b,c$.  The solution that is real and has $0 < b < c$ turns out to be
$$ b = 3^{1/6}, c =  2 \cdot 3^{1/6}$$
And now you should be able to figure out the area of the triangle.